# Using the word 'yore' in ways other than "of yore"

Tags: grammar, archaicisms

Whenever I read the word 'yore' in a sentence, it's almost always used to say "of yore".
For example:

"The ways of yore have withered"

Are there other grammatically valid ways, however old or unusual, to use the word 'yore'?
Which, if any, of the following sentences are grammatically valid?

- "I remember yore's ways"
- "That was yore, this is now"
- "Yore he came, and has ruled since"
- "Our once green yore home is now barren"

I will appreciate any examples of valid alternative usage, including ways that I didn't mention. Let's try to list every valid way to use 'yore'.

Comment: It's an archaic word which has been preserved only in this one phrase.

Comment: Yore going to have trouble finding another use.

Answer (score 3):

### In modern English? No

In a [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) search for `* yore`, most hits were for "of yore". Filtering through the rest, I got almost all irrelevant results (e.g., last names and a dialect spelling of "your"). All that remain were of the pattern "of * yore", like "Parisian couture shows of generations yore" in Harpers Bazaar (2011).

### Before that? Go crazy

In Middle English, there was a lot more variety as shown by the [Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED54029), too much to list here in full. One example is "yorefather" (meaning "forefather") as in "Oure ȝorefader hit con mysseȝeme" from *Pearl* (Nero A.10).

Comment: This answer is tantalizing, but would be pretty useless if that link broke. Surely the dozen or so collocations in the dictionary listing wouldn't be too much to reproduce.

Comment: What do you think about this sentence? It's unusual, but is it grammatically valid?

`"LOST TAPES, WARPED vinyl records, and scratched CDs have historically been the relics of hip-hop yore."`

Source: [https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-features/livemixtapes-blog-era-relaunch-1234721378/]

Comment: @LudvigBoysen Grammatical. It matches the pattern "of * yore", which I did mention seeing (though it is rare).

Comment: Adding an adjective or adverb before 'yore' doesn't change how it's used. For example, "the beliefs of Christian yore", is not actually different. I overreacted to someone doing that, hence my earlier comment